# jQuery .load() from Flash

Tags: jquery, actionscript

I need to call some jQuery `.load()` function from flash.

i Use this:

```
import flash.external.*;

on (release){
    ExternalInterface.call('show_alert','teste.asp');
}
```

and on my page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

      function show_alert(){

          $("#conteudo").load(msg);

          //alert("qualquer");

       };

     });

</script>
```

But the `teste.asp` is not loaded inside the div `#conteudo`. I'm Using AS2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the function to the global scope.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_alert(msg){

      $("#conteudo").load(msg);

      //alert("qualquer");

   };
</script>
```

You shouldn't need the `$(document).ready()` in this case, however, if you find that you do, place it inside of the function instead of outside of it.

Edit: Also, you aren't accepting the msg parameter on your function, fixed in my code.

Comment: not work...

see my online example: http://alsite.com.br/djmarcilio/teste.html Click on green square.

Comment: Running `show_alert('teste.asp')` in the console works, the problem is with your flash, it doesn't seem to be even trying to call the function.

Comment: yeah.. i make this: `import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

bt.onRelease = function()
{
 ExternalInterface.call("abrirPag","teste.asp");
};`